# How to sum up the cost and provide 0 value in the initiate value in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset schema like below:

```
 ID  Date  cost
  1  day1  20
  2  day2  30
  2  day2  18
  3  day3  20
  1  day1  23
  1  day2  26
...etc
```

And I want to build a table like this:

```
Day    id  start_balance  day_cost_amount
day1   1      0               43
day2   1      43              26
day2   2      0               48
day3   3      0               20
...etc
```

As the table shown, day_cosy_amount is the sum of cost for the specified ID in one day; the start balance is started with 0 balance for each ID: day2 start_balance=day1 start balance+day1_cost_amount. 
Here is the problem, I do not know how to give the "0" value for all of the ID in start_balance, and how SQL queries should be.

Can someone provide any idea or solutions?

Answer (score -1):

In any other database you would use a cumulative sum.  In MySQL, one method uses correlated subqueries:

```
select id, date, sum(amount) as date_cost_amount,
       coalesce( (select sum(t2.amount)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.date < t.date
                 ), 0
               ) as start_balance
from t
group by id, date;
```

Comment: Would you mind tell me what is the t2 and what is the t2.amount in the coalesce statement?

Comment: Those are table aliases, a fundamental part of the SQL language.